# Highchart Js Column Chart Stacked and Grouping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I using column stacked and grouped chart for comparing.

Check this example code : @fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wvT85/

I am trying to compare two male stacks

I want the grouped chart have same colors for the item and no repeated legends.

i.e where ever john is used it should have same color and legand should have only one john not two.

Can any one help me on this code.

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of fruits'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                stack: 'male'
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
                stack: 'male'
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
                stack: 'male2'
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
                stack: 'male2'
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 Johns to begin with?  I don't understand what the distinction is

Comment: @ben336 i a comparing two series so each series is having john. I am identifying the different series using the stack. here two stacks are male and male2

Comment: Could you give us some insight to what you are actually trying to visualize? May be there is a better visualization alternative?

Comment: @JugalThakkar: I want visualize a comparison chart. I am achieving it by using the stack option here. in this demo male stack is compared with male2 stack. Is there any other way to visualize that.

Answer (score 3):

Use LinkedTo...

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.linkedTo

The demo of it is below:

```
linkedTo: ':previous',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/

That way the legend is still functional, and you don't need to set the colors the same.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem recently. So what I did is, combine two of the answers above to solve the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/sanshila/2g79dhds/1/

```
series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male',
            color: '#6666FF',
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    this.visible ? this.chart.get('johnId').hide() : this.chart.get('johnId').show();
                }
            }
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            id: 'johnId',
            color: '#6666FF',
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'male2'
        }]
```

Comment: I like this approach best. However, it does not yet scale nicely as each series needs it's own id. Maybe `this.series.forEach(function (serie) { if (serie.name == myname) .. }  )` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define the series colors and hide the 2nd set in the legend to do what you want, but this doesn't really link the data.  It won't hide both johns if you click in the legend for instance.  This type of associating 2 points in different series isn't supported as far as I know.  I would say that I think you might want to rethink how you're representing your data, I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

series: [{
                name: 'John',
                color:'blue',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                stack: 'male'
            },  {
                name: 'John',
                color:'blue',
                showInLegend:false,
                data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
                stack: 'male2'
            }]
        });

http://jsfiddle.net/wvT85/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/b3AF9/21/

As Ben said, manually set the color for the stacks. Then give ids to the second stack and add

```
event: {
  legendItemClick: function(event){
     this.visible? 
       this.chart.get('Joe2').hide() :
       this.chart.get('Joe2').show();
  }
}
```

to series in the first stack.